Is it valid to do a repeated mesure anova when I want to compare means of a matrix question (one answer per row, 5pt likert scale, dependent sample)?
We asked participants to rate different items (matrix question, 12 Items (rows) & 5-pt Likert scale (one answer per row)). The rows were randomised in the survey.
Question: How do I compare the means of the items? I want to know if they are sig. higher/lower than the others.
It sounds like basic. If it's just two means I simply did a t-test. But somehow I don't get what test I possibly could use to check how the mean between the 12 organisations (=my dependent variables) is sign. different. Keeping in mind that the sample is dependent (I have no UV/groups).
What came to my mind was a repeated mesure anova ... what do you think? I know, normally the example for a RM Anova is "the same dependent measured at different points in time". I have "different dependent variable, measured in slightly different points in time".
Or is there anything else you'd check?

I don't see how you have a "different dependent variable". If you do, then there may not be much you can do, but I'm not clear on what's going on. // If the DV is a single Likert item, then you might not want to compare means at all. You might want a nonlinear multilevel model.

The question is unclear. Do you want to compare the means of the participants' answers to 12 Likert type questions, accross organizations? (particpants belonging to different organizations?). If that is the case, this is just plain old 1-way ANOVA. BUT... The DV is Likert, and hence ordinal; ANOVA is not appropriate for such data. Kruskal-Wallis test (or a series of Brunner-Munzel tests) are more appropriate.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you for checking! Sorry for not being more clear!
The question is if there is more trust for one organisation. The participants do not belong to any of the organisations, but answered each row of the matrix. (shown in row =differnet organisations, shown in column = 5pt likert skale, 1 "not at all" [...] 5 "completely").

@jginestet My prof told me to treat the likert skale as interval, not ordinal in this setting (all scale points had a verbal/numerical reference). With that mindset I could go for comparing the means otherwise I'm left with comparing frequencies. Anova would work if I had groups. But it's just one sample.
Do you have any idea how I could compare the means (within sample & more than 2 variables)?

Your prof may have told you to treat Likert data as interval-scale, but that is an incorrect advice/suggestion;  see e.g. this post on CV https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/540501/likert-data-and-likert-scales-ordinal-or-interval.  Now, if you have to follow your prof's bad advice, then use a plain old vanilla 1-way ANOVA; it will compare the 12 means of the scores accross all subjects.  But you have in fact paired data (same subjects); so you may instead use a series of paired t-tests, with multiple comparison correction (Sidak?)....ctd

And if you want to read more on why it is controversial (if not plain ill-advised) to treat aggregates of Likert scores, you may want to read the following https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/80oe0o/debate_are_likert_scales_ordinal_or_interval/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/14cm790/q_can_i_make_likert_scale_into_interval_data/
