# Is Movie Rating a discrete or ordinal categorical variable?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning

This movie rating is from a scale from 0 to 5 with no in between values.

Can I say that it is discrete variable and calculate things like movie rating average?

Comment: It depends, what is the goal behind calculating the score average?

Comment: The way I use the words all categorical variables are discrete. If the issue is just how much sense it makes to take averages of movie ratings, it depends, but this is an existing question.

Comment: Here is another thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67551/calculate-mean-of-ordinal-variable

Comment: If the mean is not a good method, what is? I have strong sympathy for anyone who says: look at the entire frequency distribution, but that doesn't rule out trying to summarize it. The answer in many texts that medians make sense but not means does not match my statistical judgement that 1,1,2,2,2 and 1,2,2,5,5 are not best summarized by the same number, given that one summarizes them at all.