converting Five point likert scale to uniform scale
*I am working on a meta-analysis project that includes mean and SD values from different publications. They have different scales. Some are calculated mean and SD of scores based on  visual analogue scales from 0 to 100. Some are based on visual analogue scale ranging from 1 to 10 with 0.5 increments and others are mean and SD of scores based on likert scale (5 point, 1 to 5).
So I thought about rescaling the mean and SD values (standardize the value of mean and SD and get the new value for mean and SD) in order to analyse them and compare them. How should I do that?*

The mean and SD don't seem relevant here. Mapping from $[1, 5]$ to $[0, 100]$ is just subtracting $1$ and multiplying by $25$. What else could it be? But how is a SD of $3.4$ possible at all with such a scale?

Essentially you are converting $1,2,3,\ldots$ to $20,40,60\ldots$. What is this even supposed to achieve?

@
Nick Cox, thanks for the comment,I just modify the question. So I would be thankful If I could have your advice.

If you have the mean $m$ and SD $s$ on some scale $x$, then the mean of $a + bx$ is $a + bm$ and the SD of $a + bx$ is $bs$. Plug in your values of $a$ and $b$.

Ah, the (in)famous 5-point Likert scale... Unfortunately, your problem is deeper than different scales. The values you get from a 5-point Likert scale are ordinal values; you can say that 2 is e.g. "more agreement" than 1, but that is all. The distances between 1 and 2, or 2 and 3 are not the same. You can compare various ordinal values, but you should not perform any arithmetic on them. Therefore, you should not compute means, or sd's; they make no sense; see here for more details. The only meaningfull quantities that should be computed with ordinal scale data are proportions, including quantiles, medians, etc (e.g., the median is 3, 75% of the answers are above 3, etc.). For the same reason, one should not use t-tests, ANOVA and other such methods; but tests such as Mann-Whitney U, Wilcoxon, Sign, etc. are valid (because they are tests on ranks, which only require the ability to compare 2 values).
It is indeed true that many papers (including the ones in your meta analysis) use 5-points Likert scales, and report means, sd's, etc. It is a very unfortunate and sad fact. See this paper for a more detailed discussion of the use, and misuse, of Likert scale data.
Now, the Visual Analogue Scale (VAS) was introduced to remedy this sad fact. The person using a VAS to answer a question is free to place their answer anywhere on the scale, w/o being forced into 5 arbitrarily labeled categories. A reasonable case can be made that such scores are now interval scale data. As a VAS also includes a 0, which represents e.g. total lack of agreement (or of pain, or...) it may even be argued that they are ratio scale data. In both cases, one can validly now perform arithmetic. This is particularly true if the exact same scale is used for several answers; then, the distance between answers truly represents the subject's subjective "distance" between the answers. In this case, means, sd's etc. do make sense (what is the average of "strongly agree" and "disagree"?).
The VAS with .05 increment is then some kind of "compromise" between a 5-point Likert and a VAS (as it is basically a 20-point Likert). If you pinch your nose, you could argue it is interval scale data (maybe?).
Some papers claim that values obtained by aggregating Likert scores (e.g. adding the Likert scores for several questions, to obtain an aggregate "index") can be treated as interval scale. I have not seen any formal proof of this, nor any indication for how many scores to aggregate, etc. The arguments are similar to the 20-point Likert: there is now enough fine resolution that whatever errors are made in the distance estimations between indeces, they are "small enough" to be ignored (brushed aside?).
So, my advice is to ignore any means and sd's coming from 5-point Likert scales. If these papers give you the actual counts or proportions/quantiles, you can use this for your meta analysis as they are valid statistics (but not means etc.). Wrt the 20-point Likert scale papers, I would not use the means/sd's either, but you can make a case that it is valid (definitively more valid than if it came from 5-point Likert scales). I would only use the true VAS data.

This is a purist position. I have some sympathy with it, but that is a larger question.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67551/calculate-mean-of-ordinal-variable/67556#67556 for one stance. In turn a purist or pedantic position on your wording is that your argument is that people should not do arithmetic, because it is illogical, not that they can not do it. Manifestly, the arithmetic is possible.

@jginestet, thanks so much for your time.

First, 0 to 100 is not "uniform scale". "Uniform scale" can mean a few different things, but not this (Googling reveals a bunch of possibilities, none of them that common, in my experience).
Second, there are various ways to transform scales. One simple way to get from 1 to 5 to 0 to 100 is to subtract 1 and then multiply by 25, so 1 goes to 0, 2 to 25, 3 to 50, 4 to 75 and 5 to 100. There are other methods, too. For instance, you could add some random noise to the result to get more than 5 distinct values, but I am not sure what purpose this would serve, other than making it look like something else. Adding noise is rarely what you want, but maybe there is a case where it is a good idea.
Third, you include the mean and sd which implies you want the new variable to have a certain mean and sd, rather than a certain range. This is possible, but you haven't told us the mean and sd you want. However, if you follow the above transformation, you will get a new mean and sd.
Fourth, it's debatable whether you should even take the mean and sd of a Likert scale. Strictly speaking, a Likerrt scale is ordinal, which means that, rather than 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 you could use  1, 10, 20, 21,100, 1000; that would obviously change the mean and sd. But ... people do take the mean and sd of Likert scales and, really, they seem to be somewhere between ordinal and interval. Especially for Likert scales with anchors (like "very much") the differences do seem better capture by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 than by  my absurd numbers. However again (sorry), using 0 to 4 instead of 1 to 5 would be sensible, and would change the mean, but not the sd.
